# Comma Separated List of Array Items

Tags: vb.net

Is there a built-in function in VB.NET which would take an array of strings and output a string of comma separated items?

Example: `function( { "Sam","Jane","Bobby"} ) --> "Sam, Jane, Bobby"`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
String.Join(",", YourArray)
```

Additionally, if you want to get all selected items from a checkboxlist (or radiobuttonlist) you could use an extension method (checkboxlist shown below):

Call Syntax:   Dim sResults As String = MyCheckBoxList.ToStringList()

```
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ToStringList(ByVal cbl As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList) As String
        Dim separator As String = ","
        Dim values As New ArrayList
        For Each objItem As UI.WebControls.ListItem In cbl.Items
            If objItem.Selected Then
                values.Add(objItem.Value.ToString)
            End If
        Next
        Return String.Join(separator, values.ToArray(GetType(String)))
    End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
string commaSep = string.Join(",", myArray);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
String.Join(",", arrayWithValues)
```

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6030362.html)

Answer (score 4):

[String.Join Method (String, array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)[])

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about VB, but C# has a String.Join method which can concatanate a string array delimited by a nominated character. Presume VB is almost identical.

Comment: The `String` class is part of the base class library and therefore available to all .NET languages.