# VB.NET; read file of comma-separated integers to an array

Tags: vb.net, csv, file-io

How can I read .txt file of comma-separated integers into array in VB.NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comma Separated List of Array Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247875/comma-separated-list-of-array-items)

Comment: I think that's the opposite.  I believe you're looking for "Split"

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Linq to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397919.aspx). I am assuming that your file has 1025 comma delineated integers in it.

```
Dim myData As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\Integers.txt") 'get your data
Dim myIntegerArray() As Integer = (From s As Integer In myData.Split(","c)).ToArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. The correct code depends on how large is your file, how do you want to process the numbers, etc.

```
Dim fileArray As String() = File.ReadAllLines("yourfilenamehere")

For i As Integer = 0 To fileArray.Length - 1
      'define array to hold each value in a cell of type string
       Dim arrayOfNumbersStoredAsStrings As String() = fileArray(i).Split(","C)
      'process the values in each line here...
Next
```

Comment: I asked just for code to put them in array. Processing is another thing. Array has to be integer type and has length 1025

Comment: So you want to store the entire file in an integer array, something like a math. matrix of 1025 column and variable number of rows?